# Merging lists with common ID in Sharepoint view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, view, sharepoint-designer

Working in Sharepoint 2010, I have a list of games (each with a unique ID).  Then I have a separate list of translations for the game, which consists of a language value (English, French, etc), and a Game ID.  So, when I add a new game to the games list, I take the ID, then enter that detail into the translations list along with each language.  I've been able to add a ListViewWebPart to the DispForm for a given game, such that it will display all available translations for that game.

However, now I've been asked to provide a View (a custom page with a webpart containing a view), that contains both the data from the Games list, and the translations for those games.  This would be fairly straightforward if working in SQL, but i'm not sure how to do this with Sharepoint.

Here is further detail:

Games List columns:

- ID
- Name
- Live Date

Translation columns (so each game will have a row for each available language):

- GameID
- Translation
- Translation Date
- Full or semi translated

What i'm looking for is a view, that groups games by Live Date, showing the game columns, plus a dynamically created column that would grab the ID for each game, query the translations list, and output all the translations into that column.

Ultimately, management wants to see what games are going live when, and in what languages.

I've looked at some way of nesting another query in the view, but am just not familar enough with SP2010 to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a webpart and would build that view myself using the server object model.

You can do it with sharepoint designer by using the Data Form Web Part, as described here...but i always found it too hard to configure:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx#_Toc245608912